# How to check if geometry is M aware?

Tags: python, arcpy, line

I am trying to determine whether my shapefile that I pass is in M-aware (has M value). I keep getting an error

```
Attribute Error: 'Polyline' object has no attribute 'hasM'
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import arcpy

def ValidInputGeometry(feat):
    is_valid_poly_line = False
    is_m_enabled = False
    error_msg = None
    if feat.type == "polyline":
        if is_m_enabled == feat.hasM:
            is_valid_poly_line = True
        else:
            error_msg = "The input geometry is not M-Aware"
    else:
        error_message = "The input geometry is not a polyline"
    return (is_valid_poly_line, error_msg)



station_interval = 10000
in_polyline_m_layer = "C:/Users/Algorithm/LWOB_levee.shp"
target_feature_rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(in_polyline_m_layer, "FID = 0", "", "", "")
layer_description = arcpy.Describe(in_polyline_m_layer)
shape_field = layer_description.ShapeFieldName

for row in target_feature_rows:
    feat = row.getValue(shape_field)

    (Valid, Msg) = ValidInputGeometry(feat)
```

Comment: Try `arcpy.Describe(in_polyline_m_layer).hasM`.

Comment: Or with your own code, layer_description.hasM ... a geometry object does not have a hasM property, but it does have a construction parameter hasM -- which may be the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the geometry objects returned from cursors are not fully attributed (no hasM, hasZ, etc.) but you can find out whether the feature class itself supports M values using the feature class [`Describe`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000002p000000) object's `hasM` property:

```
arcpy.Describe(yourFeatureClass).hasM
```